# UIScrollView Skips at Bottom

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit

In my app I have a UIScrollView with not many subviews that doesn't use Auto Layout but rather plain old Autosizing to fill itself to the size of the view controller. The only line of code that interacts with it is this:

```
settingScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600);
```

The problem is that only on the iPhone 4/4S, it does this skip sort of thing when you reach the bottom of the scroll view. [Here is a video of what happens.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5kww1bnovil3fqg/IMG_0045.MOV.mov)

Is this a UIKit bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be a bug with iOS 7. This was a scrollview in a scrollview which, while I know is not best practice, worked just fine on the iPhone 5/5S form factor it had the strange behavior mentioned above on the iPhone 4/4S. Moving the daughter scrollview out of the parent scrollview and having it move as though it were in the parent scrollview.